# Determining element position of one array based on other related arrays

Tags: arrays, vba, math, relation

I have 3 arrays dynamic arrays(sizes determined during runtime):

```
dim arrName() as String 
dim arrQty() as Integer
dim arrDate() as Date
```

These arrays are interrelated: eg.,

*1st array: I have 3 procedures named Procedure1, Procedure2, Procedure3 - arrName(Procedure1, Procedure2, etc.), respectively, size will be 3.

2nd array: quantity of each procedure prescribed, respectively - arrQty(Qty1, Qty2, etc.), respectively size will be 3. Qty2 - means Procedure2 prescribed Qty2 times...

3rd array: dates of procedures prescribed sequentially, eg., if arrQty(1) = 2, it means the first 2 elements of arrDate() would be 2 dates for Procedure1. The size of the array would be sum of elements of arrQty(). Eg, if arrQty() = [2,2,4] then size of arrDate() is 8.*

The question is; knowing the position of arrDate() element,  how analytically determine its name?

E.g. the arrDate(4) is related to arrName(2), arrDate(7) to arrName(3), etc...

P.S. I can create 4th array with size of arrDate() and fill it respectively with elements of arrName(), e.g. [Procedure1, Procedure1, Procedure2, etc. ], but is there more clever way?

---

UPDATED

I don't like Exit statements. I wonder if below will yield the solution as Brian suggested?

```
Private Function FindProcedure(ByVal DateIndex As Integer) As String 
  Dim i As Integer
  Dim qty As Integer  
  i = 0  
  qty = arrQty(i)
  Do While DateIndex >= qty
       i = i + 1
       qty = qty + qty(i)
  Loop
  FindProcedure = arrName(i)
End Function
```

Comment: Do you have to use 3 arrays, or could you do it a different way?

Comment: The idea is: there are three dimensions: name, quantity, and date; and they are related to one another as described above. I may be done done differently

Comment: In my answer below, I implemented the solution based upon your original idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming 1-based arrays, the following function will give the Procedure Name for the given Date Index:

```
Private Function FindProcedure(ByVal DateIndex As Integer) As String
   Dim i As Integer
   Dim qty As Integer

   For i = LBound(arrQty) To UBound(arrQty)
      qty = qty + arrQty(i)

      If DateIndex <= qty Then
         FindProcedure = arrName(i)
         Exit Function
      End If
   Next
End Function
```

Based on feedback from the OP, here's another version that doesn't use an Exit statement and works just as well:

```
Private Function FindProcedure(ByVal DateIndex As Integer) As String
   Dim i As Integer
   Dim qty As Integer

   i = 1
   qty = arrQty(1)

   Do While DateIndex > qty
      i = i + 1
      qty = qty + arrQty(i)
   Loop

   FindProcedure = arrName(i)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, like default, VBA uses zero based arrays. Meaning that the iteration between array elements starts with zero. Except cases when you do use `Option Base 1` or do explicitly declare like them `Dim arrName(1 To 3)`. The next piece of code will show you how to match the example arrays from your question. I assumed that both dates (of the `arrDate`) of a pair, belong to an element of shorter arrays. If not, you can choose only the line matching your need. The code returns both of them on different lines:

```
Sub testArraysMatching()
 Dim arrName() As String
 Dim arrQty(2) As Integer
 Dim arrDate(5) As Date
 Dim i As Long

 arrName() = Split("Procedure1,Procedure2,Procedure3", ",")
 arrQty(0) = 3: arrQty(1) = 6: arrQty(2) = 10
 arrDate(0) = Date: arrDate(1) = Date + 1: arrDate(2) = Date + 2: arrDate(2) = Date + 3
 arrDate(3) = Date + 4: arrDate(4) = Date + 5: arrDate(5) = Date + 6
  Debug.Print LBound(arrName), UBound(arrName) 'it will return 0 and 2
 For i = LBound(arrName) To UBound(arrName)
    'return the corresponding quantity:
    Debug.Print "Quantity for " & arrName(i) & " is " & arrQty(i)
    'return the coresponding (both) dates:
    Debug.Print "Date 1 for " & arrName(i) & " is " & arrDate(i * 2)
    Debug.Print "Date 2 for " & arrName(i) & " is " & arrDate(i * 2 + 1)
 Next i

 'find name for a Date element:
 Dim testDate As Date, boolFound As Boolean
   testDate = Date + 10
   For i = LBound(arrDate) To UBound(arrDate)
        If arrDate(i) = testDate Then
            Debug.Print arrName(Int(i / 2)): boolFound = True
        End If
   Next i
   If Not boolFound Then MsgBox "The date """ & testDate & """ not found in ""arrDate""."
End Sub
```

Of course, you can use a 2D array instead of the first two. Or use dictionaries, collections etc. The code only tries answering the question.

Comment: But given a date element, how do you find the name?

Comment: @Brian M Stafford: Vice versa... I will add to the answer this scenario, too. Even if the iteration method may be not the best, I think it is easier to be understood by somebody not too experienced.

Comment: @FaneDuru: you design have 2 dates for each name, actually it should have 3 for Procedure1, 6 for Procedure2, etc., totaling to 19 dates. In that case diving date index to 2 wouldn't be a solution